# Undefined index when sending data to PHP file from jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've researched about this issue (I read a lot of StackOverflow questions) and I still can't figure out a solution.

I get the id HTML 'a' attribute value with jQuery when I click the link and then I need send it to a php file which will do a database query. I tried by using `$.ajax` and `$.post` jQuery functions and I get the same error.

With `$.post`

```
var idElement;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.linkElement').click(function(){
      idElement= $(this).attr('id');
      console.log(idElement); // Shows id value on console
      $.post("showElement.php", idElement).done(function (){
         alert("All went good"); 
      });
      $(document.body).load("showElement.php");         
  });
});
```

With `$.ajax`

```
var idElement;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.linkElement').click(function(){
          idElement= $(this).attr('id');
          console.log(idElement); // Shows id value on console
          $.post("showElement.php", idElement).done(function (){
             alert("All went good"); 
          });

            $.ajax({
              url: "showElement.php",  
              type: "POST",
              data: {'idElement':idElement}
            });

        });
});
```

When I use `$_POST['idElement']` in my `showElement.php` file I get the following:

```
Notice: Undefined index: idElement in C:\xampp\htdocs\path\to\showElement.php on line 28
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I tested this with Firebug and it says it's ok. And data shown in Firebug Console appears correctly, but PHP file is not shown in browser (var_dump returns values it should have).

Any idea about this?

Comment: instead of `method:"POST"`, Use `type:"POST"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had it like you said, and after searching in jQuery website I noticed it may should be 'method' instead 'type', so I changed it.
If I leave it like 'type', showElement.php is not shown.
Any that should I know?

Comment: In your `showElement.php` try to echo the `$_POST['idElement']`

Comment: Edit your post with `PHP` code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I said in a comment, I came across with a solution that doesn't use JavaScript.

I'm working with Twig for templates and what I did is to forget about jQuery for this and use `$_GET` instead `$_POST` in `showElement.php`, since I'm not sending sensitive data (passwords or usernames) and I just appended

```
?idElement=anyElementId
```

to the path to showElement.php, getting, for example, the following URI:

```
http://localhost/Project/showElement.php?idElement=1
```

In my showElement.php:

```
$anElement= ElementQuery::create()->findPk($_GET['idElement']); // Retrieve and element with Propel
$_SESSION['element'] = $anElement; // Save the element in $_SESSION['element'] variable
```

And to show the information I display my showElement.twig template:

```
$twig->display("showElement.twig", array('element') => $_SESSION['element']); // Display Twig template and pass arguments in an array
```

In my Twig template (showElement.twig)

```
<!-- Link to be clicked -->
    <a id="{{element.getId}}" class="linkElement" href="./../Project/showElement.php?idElement={{element.getId}}">{{element.getTitle}}</a>
```

It's just one solution. I don't know if it's a good way to do it, but it works.
I think I can save the object in the array directly, avoiding using $_SESSION  variable for this but, I did it in case I need to use the retrieved element in others PHP files.

If anyone finds another solution for this, can post it here.

Thanks everyone for your help :)

**EDIT** Link to thread that helps me: [Ajax send the data, but php doesn't recieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948458/ajax-send-the-data-but-php-doesnt-recieve) (Title describes just what I figured out with Firebug :P)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```js
      $.post("showElement.php", idElement).done(function (){
         alert("All went good"); 
      });
```

for this

```js
         $.post("showElement.php", {'idElement': idElement}).done(function (){
         alert("All went good"); 
      });
```

You forgot to add the key in the 'data' parameter. And I think you might be seeing this only when you use $.post because the $.ajax is correct. Comment the $.ajax one and try what I suggested you or comment the $.post one and try the $.ajax.

Here you have an example
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-post.htm

PS : Sorry, I can't answer as a comment yet.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I did what you suggested me but, unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. I don't know what's going on... Maybe is the way I load the showElement.php file... $(document.body).load("verPregunta.php"); that should be done by other way?

Comment: How are you accesing your php file? I'm thinking you're accessing the file directly through your browser. If firebug reports that is ok, it means what I'm telling you.

I tried your code and neither of those two prints what is returned from the file.

So basically what you are doing, I think, is you are running your file with javascript code and then you browse your php file in two different tabs (to be more clear).

Am I right?

Comment: My intention was to open the .php file in the current tab. That .php file does a database query and shows data (all that in the same file). I've found a solution. I'll post it answers section shorty :)

Answer (score 0):

`POST` method can be used like

```
$.post("showElement.php", 
{idElement: idElement},
 function (result) {
   alert("All went good"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you are doing anything wrong. Instead of trying to fetch a data using some `key`,

Try `var_dump($_POST)` to see whether you are getting any `POST` datas at all

**NOTE:**
Try setting `datatype` also in your `ajax` request

**EDIT** : Inlcude the `contentType`  in your request. check below

```
  $.ajax({
          url: "showElement.php",  
          type: "POST",
          contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          dataType: 'html', //or json whatever data that you return from server side
          data: {'idElement':idElement}
        });
```

I think setting the `contentType` should work.

Comment: It returns array(0) { }, I'm not getting any POST datas, for sure...
Any Idea or alternative?

Comment: Did you check console for any kind of syntax errors? Also did you try setting datatype?

Comment: Yes, I got a kind of warning that says: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
I reseached for the warning/error and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639335/javascript-console-log-causes-error-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thr) and still the same thing...

Comment: okay so did you try explicitly putting "async: true" in your ajax request as given in one of the solutions, may be the async parameter is set to false and asynchronous request is not being sent

Comment: Yes, I did. And showElement.php file is not showing at all... If I figure out something I'll let you know.